# Identifying duplicate files based on data content in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I get files to a shared location . Every file has different meta ie. file name, date created.

I have to extract the data using SSIS if and only if file content is different than previously processed files.

Comment: to check if data is different, i guess you will have to see that data. Marking unclear.

Comment: Hi  i mean if any corrector is changed in file content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got work around

SSIS execute process task and i have called FC.exe

http://www.howtogeek.com/206123/how-to-use-fc-file-compare-from-the-windows-command-prompt/

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly straight-forward -

1. Use a `ForEach` container configured to `For Each File` setting. `Folder name` would be the shared location. `File Name` should be a wildcard (example, *.csv)
2. Create a table in SQL called `LoadedFiles` which will hold the names of the files loaded. Note that when you create the `ForEach` container you would have also created a variable that would hold the file-name. Now in the `ForEach` container, check if the value in this variable exists already in the `LoadedFiles` table. If it doesn't, only then load.

I've assumed that all the files have the same metadata (column names and data types). Even if they do not, you can employ the same logic.

Also, if it isn't obvious, for this to work you need to insert a new row into the  `LoadedFiles` table every time you do decide to load a file.

EDIT: It seems same file name does not equate to same content for the OP. In that case, he should just do a `MERGE` on the SQL table instead of a blind insert.

`MERGE` on the primary key and `IF MATCHED` do nothing else `INSERT`

Comment: hi  table file load can be used in case file name  (meta of file ) are same.

Comment: In that case the above approach should work just fine.

Comment: hi think i have a file a.csv  content 'a'  and another file b.csv and it also have same data 'a' then i should not process b.csv  but if b.csv have 'a ' then i have to process .

Comment: In that case just do a `MERGE` into your table every time?

Comment: i have some other task to do .and there is possibility of same row data from two files in case of MERGE it will not work.